# How to I go through a for() loop without opening webdriver.Chrome() repeatedly?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My current code is:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

first_page_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Action/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
first_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Action/#p='
rest_url = '&tab=NewReleases'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(first_page_url)
soup_page = driver.page_source
print(type(soup_page))
soup_page = soup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
page_numbers = soup_page.find('div',{'id':'NewReleases_ctn'})
page_numbers = page_numbers.text.split()
#print(page_numbers)
last_page_number = page_numbers[13]
print(last_page_number)
last_page_number = last_page_number.replace(',','')
last_page_number = int(last_page_number)
last_page_number = last_page_number / 15
print(last_page_number)
last_page_number = round(last_page_number)
pages = range(0,last_page_number)
index_number = 0
nana = 1

for page in pages:
    page = first_url + str(pages[index_number]) + rest_url
    print(type(page))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(5)
    soup_page = driver.page_source
    #print(type(soup_page))
    soup_page = soup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    new_releases = soup_page.find('div',{'id':'NewReleasesRows'})
    containers = new_releases.find_all('a',{'class':'tab_item'})
    container = containers[0]
    driver.close()
    for container in containers:
        title = container.find('div',{'class':'tab_item_name'}).text
        print(nana,title)
        nana = nana + 1
    index_number =index_number + 1
```

The code works as intended except, that every time it loops through the first `for` loop, it opens the `driver.Chrome()`.
**Is there a way of using the opened browser, again and again, other than opening a new one every time it loops through?**

Answer (score 0):

driver object is created global and you are again invoking chrome in commented line. So remove that line and all pages will work in same chrome.

```
for page in pages:
    page = first_url + str(pages[index_number]) + rest_url
    print(type(page))
    // driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
    driver.get(page)
```

Comment: I removed `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` but then it would scrape data of the first web page repeatedly. Should I add some `time.sleep()` or something?

Comment: **OR** alternatively, how do I close the `data:,` tab in the opened browser?

Answer (score 0):

Would loop all 71 pages instead. Without the need for grabbing any page number or etc.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(first_page_url)

while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[not(@class='pagebtn disabled')and @id='NewReleases_btn_next']"))).click()
    except:
        break
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```